# How wise is sitting for PMP exam in changing year?

Tags: pmp

I was planning to sit for PMP by the end of this year (November/December). I've through some books, prepared my experience documentation, obtained initial approval from supervisors, and set plans to get membership, and (if audit goes well), sit for the exam within 6 months.

However, few weeks ago, I noticed a new announcement by PMI stating the [PMP is changing in 2015](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Project-Management-Professional-PMP.aspx). When you read more, you find that the changes are not finalized yet (will be in 3 days form now), and that the last exam date for the current version is 1st November.

I do not expect I will be sitting for the exam before this date. Hence, most likely, I should start preparing for the new version. But at the same time, I do not know when to start that, because I'm not sure if the materials for the new version will be available soon or not. For example, I decided to prepare using PMBOK and another book called [Head first PMP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449364918). But the current versions of each up to now cover the current PMP version and not the coming one.

Given the above information, my questions is, how wise is preparing for PMP this year? Will I suffer any serious changes (lack of material, examples ... etc), or it is not really that be significant? PMI changes PMP every couple of years. Have any one experienced any of these changes and their effects? What is the advice?

[image]

Comment: I suspect if you contact the PMI directly they will be happy to answer this question.

Comment: Actually probably not. PMI is notoriously tight lipped about things like this. They don't want to impact current people planning to take the test.

Comment: Our trainer told us during the exam prep course (in mid 2015) to not worry too much about the changing exams. If you know your stuff you'll get it done, either way. Which I actually hope will be true ;)

Answer (score 2):

PMI regularly updates the PMP test based on the changes to the PMBOK which are driven by how business and the art of project management is changing.

Whether you delay or take the test before November really comes down to your readiness. If you've already started to study, then there is no reason to delay. Material for the new test will come out in a couple more months and you'd have less time to study with the new materials.

If you're confident with your ability to pass then test, then take it.

I can tell you that when they did their big update in I think 2010, the general agreement was to try and get in to take the test before the change. That was a fairly significant change in how the test was run, so the incentive was high.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the opportunity cost.

In other words. Are you going to lose many opportunities because of the delay in getting the certification?

1. If you're expecting an internal promotion in 2015, and being a PMP will give you an advantage, you could risk and take the test.
2. If you're thinking on searching for another job in 2015, the PMP could give you an advantage to succeed in your quest.
3. If you think you're going to be in the same job in December 2015, then you could simply wait and get the PMP in 2016, when the dust from the changes has settled.

Both for cases 1 and 2: you could give a try to the current version. If you pass, all right. If you fail, your knowledge will still be with you for taking the test in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Due to circumstances, I did not take the PMP test short after a change, although it was originally planned that way, , but only 6 months later. So I cannot say anything about that.

However, one piece of advice I can say is about the **training material**: have a good look at them before you buy, because I ordered a book that was 'adapted to the new exam', only to find out it wasn't. They only added an aditional chapter online that covered some of the changes. The book itself was not changed. It only had a sticker on it pretending it was.

I guess in order to get rid of excess stock, publishers use tricks like that. Adding some content online to ensure they're legally ok.

So make sure the materials you use are indeed adapted to the new version of the test.

Good luck